# CollectionView datasource method called with incorrect CollectionView argument

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uikit

I have two collection views as properties of a custom view as properties.  So lets call them `self.collViewA` and `self.collViewB`.  When implementing datasource methods, I use if statements to configure the correct collection view with the correct information.  I simply use `isEqual:` to check the `collectionView` parameter to each datasource callback.  This works for every datasource callback except for `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`.

My implementation is as follows:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if ([collectionView isEqual:self.collViewA]) {
            return CGSizeMake(25,25);
   }
   if ([collectionView isEqual:self.collViewB]) {
      return CGSizeMake(50,50);
   }
   return CGSizeMake(10,10);
}
```

The problem seems to be that when both collection views are instantiated in my setup method (called after initializing the custom view that is the super of these collection views),  only the second if statement passes and both collection views have 50,50 sized cells.  If I remove the code that instantiates the second collection view, than the first if WILL pass and I'll get 25,25 sized cells for the right view, but obviously no second collection view.

What I don't get is how I use the same conditional logic with `isEqual:` on every other callback and have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tag to solve that

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (collectionView.tag == 1) {
            return CGSizeMake(25,25);
   }
   if (collectionView.tag == 2) {
      return CGSizeMake(50,50);
   }
   return CGSizeMake(10,10);
}
```

Comment: i find that a bit of a hack though because clearly the collectionView argument is included just so a user can differentiate different one's.  fwiw, i got it to work by using two separate `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`'s for each collection view.